# Top navigation bar doesn't appear

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a top navigation bar that has a logout button which returns the user back to the login screen and wipes their access token from their keychain.

I am working on adding a slide out menu bar, however, my top navigation bar is not appearing and I can't seem to get it to appear.

I am presenting this view on successful login using the following excerpt of code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let homePage = 
        self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
        "HomePageViewController") as! HomePageViewController
    self.present(homePage, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of present `HomePageViewController`,  you have to present `UINavigationController` of `HomePageViewController`.

- Set storyboard ID for `UINavigationController` of `HomePageViewController`. For example, you set storyboard ID for `UINavigationController` is `HomePageNavigation`
- Replace your code with the code below.

  ```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let homePage = 
          self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
  "HomePageNavigation") as! UINavigationController
      self.present(homePage, animated: true)
  }
  ```

Select `UINavigationController` of `HomePageController` on Storyboard
[image]

[image]

Change Storyboard Id Of `UINavigationController`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer however i'm a bit confused. I understand changing my code but i'm confused as to what variables I change regarding storyboard/class IDs. My homepage view has a class and storyboard ID of: HomePageViewController. My navigation controller attached to that home page has nothing set.

Comment: Sorry, I spent a few more minutes going over your answer and realized what you want. Set the storyboard ID of the controller to HomePageNavigation and append my code. It worked. I can see the navigation bar

Comment: @Harrison great, i have updated my answer too. You can take a look if you need.